# Docker + Django + MySQL - End of list of non-natively partitioned tables

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, docker

I am trying to use Docker with Django and MySQL database but unfortunately during `docker-compose up` at some point it stops on `End of list of non-natively partitioned tables` and my server is not starting. When I am using my app without Docker it works. Any suggestions what is wrong?

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
db:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    - MYSQL_USER=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=pri
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3
 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 RUN mkdir /code
 WORKDIR /code
 ADD requirements.txt /code/
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ADD . /code/
```

`settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'pri',
        'USER': 'root',
        'HOST': 'db',
    }
}
```

It seems to me that my problem may be associated with structure of directories. To wit it looks in this way:

```
`DockerContainer`:
- docker-compose.yml
- Dockerfile
- requirements.txt
- ProjectDirectory
```

in `ProjectDirectory` I have `virtualenv` and Project:

```
- bin
- include
- lib
- pip-selfcheck.json
- Project
```

in `Project` I have git repository, back-end and front-end:

```
- backendFolder
- frontendFolder
```

in `backendFolder`:

```
-backendProject
```

in `-backendProject`:

```
- my project with `manage.py` etc.
```

Comment: And where are your migrations?

Comment: I'm not sure where they should be?

Comment: How did you connect to database from djago, what is in your DATABASE settings section?

Comment: I have added my database setttings in post.

Comment: It won't be 127.0.0.1 it will be db, because it's in the other container which you named 'db'.

Comment: And change links to
 links:
    - db : db

Comment: It looks better. Does ti work?

Comment: I get - ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: web.links contains an invalid type, it should be a string

Comment: Ahhh, yes. Remove that link part completely from compose file

Comment: Okey, I have done like in the first post, but still `[Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables dockerpri_web_1 exited with code 2`

Answer (score 0):

I think your compose file should be like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Somepassword
        MYSQL_DATABASE: pri
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: strongpassword
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
  web:
     build: .
     command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
     volumes:
        - .:/code
     ports:
        - "8000:8000"
     depends_on:
        - db
     links:
        - db
```

and settings like this

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'pri',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'strongpassword',
        'HOST': 'db',
    }
}
```

Comment: `docker-compose up` returns
`ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 4, column 3
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 10, column 4`

Comment: maybe there are seom indentation errors, check them

Comment: I have tried in two editors but still the same, is it working on your computer? Should ports not be at the same level as environment?

Comment: no, ports should be on the same level as enviroment

Comment: So now I get `In file './docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not a NoneType.`

Comment: dude, it's really hard to make all the indententions right in SO inline editor. ))) indent everything under services:

Comment: Okey, I have found problem, but now I have still problem with `End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
dockerpri_web_1 exited with code 2
` Should XAMPP be running?

Comment: When I have XAMPP running I get - `Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.`

Comment: You should terminate your XAMPP because you start mysql from containter a don't need XAMPP mysql any more

Answer (score 0):

"End of list ..." is the informational message from MySQL - it lists thetables that use deprecated "partition" engine (even if there are none) and ends with this message. It may [take long time for MySQL to start](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85830), but if you see "end of list" message then it's already done.

```
[Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
[Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
```

This shouldn't cause any issues.

Just for reference, this is how you can check that your MySQL server is upand running:

1. Start with `docker-compose up -d`. Use of `-d` means your containers will be *detached* from the terminal, running in the background.
2. Check that all services are up with `docker-compose ps`. If any of them says something like `Exit (1)` then that particular service is not running.
3. Check the MySQL server. Run `docker-compose exec mysql mysql -uroot -pstrongpassword -e 'SELECT version();' pri`.

**Now, what actually fails is your Django app.** Based on comments to the neighboring answer (`dockerpri_web_1 exited with code 2`), what happens is your `runserver` process dying. We can't know why it does, though - there is not enough information in your messages. I don't think it's related to MySQL, though - Django should start even if database is down. It would just respond with 500 errors, as it won't be able to connect.

My suggestions:

1. As it was suggested, upgrade to Compose version 2 (there is an example in another answer - it's good). If you don't plan to access MySQL from your host, you may consider removing `port: "3306:3306"` from the `mysql` service. This way, it won't conflict if there's anything else would be already listening on 3306 (XAMPP or whatever).
2. Stop everything. `docker-compose down`. Make check that no container would interfere by taking ports `3306` or `8000` to itself (use `docker ps` to check).
3. Run MySQL in background: `docker-compose up -d mysql`. Wait a few seconds and check that it is still alive with `docker-compose ps` (it should say "Up" for "dockerpri_mysql_1").
4. Now, start a shell in your Django container: `docker-compose run --rm --service-ports web /bin/bash`. Run `python manage.py check` or `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` there. Now, hopefully you should get only the relevant error messages, so you would be able to fix things. (If the `runserver` would exit silently, that's a bad omen - hope your case would be simpler)
5. Exit with `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - the container will be cleaned up for you automatically (`--rm` flag takes care of this).

Comment: I have updated first post. I have described what exactly I'm going to achieve.